# Is there a way to update the a response value on each checkbox click in angular 11 dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my response. I am looping the data needed and resources and displaying it in tiles with checkbox. I have a field cost estimation in the footer which will have usd 0(minValue) - usd 0(maxValue) at the footer. What i want to do here is onclick of checkbox i want to update the minValue and maxvalue. I can have multiple selections. I can select combination of data needed and resources. So how to do this dynamically in typescript? Any help is appreciated.

```
   {
   "DataNeeded":[
   {
     "MinValue":0.00,
     "MaxValue":0.00
   },
   {
     "MinValue":0.00,
     "MaxValue":0.00
   }
  ],
  "Resources":[
   {
     "MinValue":0.00,
     "MaxValue":0.00
    },
    {
     "MinValue":0.00,
     "MaxValue":0.00
    },
    {
     "MinValue":0.00,
     "MaxValue":0.00
    }
 ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we has an array of object (e.g. elemens) and we want "checked", we can use an auxiliar array or booleans,e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements;let i=index">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="auxArray[i]">
</div>
```

So, it's "easy" filter the elements selected, in a function

```
auxArray:boolean[]=[]  //<--declare the array
getSelected(){
   const selected=this.elements.filter((x,index)=>this.auxArray[index])
}
```

Yes the "filter" method of an array admit a second argument with the index of the iteration, so the expresion before indicate that if the array in the position 1 is true -our second check-box-, pass the filter

So we can do something interesting with the elements selected, e.g. calculate the sum of one property

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements;let i=index">

  <!--I divided the "banana" syntax-->
  <input type="checkbox" 
         [ngModel]="auxArray[i]" 
         (ngModelChange)="auxArray[i]=$event;calculateSelect()">
</div>
the sum of MinValue is {{sum}}
```

And in .ts

```
//declare a variable sum
sum:number=0;
calculateSelect(){
   const selected=this.elements.filter((x,index)=>this.auxArray[index])
   this.sum=selected.reduce((a,b)=>a+b.MinValue,0)
}
```